# Gatsby loads website unstyled for first time (with refresh it looks good again)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have built two projects now with the help of gatsbyjs.

Both have a loading problem: When I first load the site, the styling completely breaks down.

I am using third party components (ant.design and semantic-ui, and I also load some google fonts). Components that have been created with styled-components appear fine, so it might be due to these packages loading.

I have used this boilerplate as a starter for both projects: https://github.com/jbolda/gatsby-source-airtable

How do I solve this loading issue? I am fine with the site loading a tiny bit slower, but in the expected styling.

Comment: Is this hosted anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I am deploying it on Netlify!

Comment: The problem doesn't fully appear in development mode: Only the search bar gets loaded slowly locally. Might be a problem with data bandwidth?

Comment: If it is a cache problem, you can append a version number `?version=1.0` to CSS/JS-files to break the cache.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this, but it didn't work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I was missing gatsby-plugin-styled-components, I was unaware that this was necessary, but makes sense now. Hope it helps others!

[Here is the plugin's gatsby page.](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/)